# How to stop camera view when another fragment is active

Tags: java, android

I got only two fragments.
for example `FragmentOne` and `FragmentTwo`.

FragmentOne got button which runs function `captureCode();` this function turning on camera and looking for barcode ( nevermind ).
But when I turn on camera in my `surfaceView` I can also see tab `FragmentTwo` and ofc I can click it. ( this is good ). But there is my problem.
If I click on `FragmentTwo` my `surfaceView` is still visible and I can't see anything from `FragmentTwo`.

How can I stop everything from `FragmentOne` when `FragmentTwo` is active?

Comment: Can you please share your fragments code and a GIF of what you are actually experiencing. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get your visible fragment with :

```
public Fragment getVisibleFragment() {
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
    List<Fragment> fragments = fragmentManager.getFragments();
    if (fragments != null) {
        for (Fragment fragment : fragments) {
            if (fragment != null && fragment.isVisible())
                return fragment;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

use :

```
    Fragment SelectedFragment = getVisibleFragment();
    if (SelectedFragment != null && (SelectedFragment.getTag() == null || !SelectedFragment.getTag().equals("fragment_tag")))
     //do something like invisible widgets...
```